# Creating list of yearly collections in GEE (Python API)

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm using GEE (Python API): I have a multi-year image collection and I'm trying to simply create a list, in which each element contains a yearly Image Collection. I've prototyped it with one year, and it works:

```
# The relevant collection is called test_coll.
start_list = ee.List(['2017-01-01', '2018-01-01'])
end_list = ee.List(['2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'])
seventeen = test_coll.filterDate(start_list.get(0), end_list.get(0))
```

However, when I take this to the multi-year level, and use a function:

```
start_list = ee.List(['2017-01-01', '2018-01-01'])
end_list = ee.List(['2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'])
year_list = ee.List.sequence(0,1)


def list_of_yearly_coll(year):
    return test_coll.filterDate(start_list.get(year), end_list.get(year))
                                
list_yr_coll = year_list.map(list_of_yearly_coll)
```

It creates a list with two image collections (as it should), but both collections contain zero elements (see image).[image: Output]

Remark: I'm not sharing the image collection here, because it goes through a fair bit of preprocessing dependent on local Python files, and I haven't exported it. I hope that the solution to this is so common that it doesn't rely on that collection.

I've tried different casting options, but I can't figure this seemingly very simple task out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know they have zero elements?  Most likely, you're simply looking at the output of a `getInfo` call or something similar, and those don't recursively expand objects in containers (like lists).  So you're probably just seeing the "outer wrapper" of the collection. You need to look at one of them explicitly to see what's in it.

```
print(ee.ImageCollection(list_yr_coll.get(0)).size().getInfo())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Noel! You were right!